# Problems with i18next language detection and integration with hapi

Tags: internationalization, i18next, hapi

I'm trying to write a new language detector plugin for i18next for integration with hapi.  There's an existing hapi-i18next plugin that is quite old (it uses an extemely old version of i18next, 1.7.10 ) and so mostly useless. And the i18next API docs are pretty vague about how to write new plugins and exactly what the language detection process is.  Does it run every time the t() function runs? should it be asynchronous?  Has anybody else out there recently integrated hapi with i18next? I realize this is rather general but i'm not sure where else to turn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is writing a hapi server *extension* rather than a plugin, and a module that runs at startup that decorates the hapi server object with the initialized `i18next` object.  The extension is installed to run `onPreHandler` and it basically clones the i18next object, attaches that instance to the request object, and detects the language (from the request header or from a query parameter), then sets the cloned instance to that language.  This way, whenever a route handler uses the `t()` function attached to the instance that's attached to the current request, we know we'll be translating into the right language.  Note that this is still for Hapi 16 (I need to port to 17/18 soon)...

Answer (score 1):

Never used hapi so far, but seems hapi evolved a lot since version 8 (what's actually used [here](https://github.com/kenkouot/hapi-i18next))

I don't know if that project is still maintained...

Perhaps you could try to create a new hapi-i18next plugin... (was not that much [code](https://github.com/kenkouot/hapi-i18next/blob/master/src/hapi-i18next.ts))

To create a languageDetector plugin, it should not be a big thing... start [here](https://www.i18next.com/misc/creating-own-plugins#languagedetector) and continue by comparing how the [express language detection](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-express-middleware/blob/master/src/LanguageDetector.js) works

In i18next the languageDetector is triggered [here](https://github.com/i18next/i18next/blob/66b1be165b2a6218091d372c339eeac1c8be0ba1/src/i18next.js#L211)
...so on init/load and on a potential language change

I hope this helps.